# Have two buttons open two different view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble with this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var team1Field: UITextField!

    @IBAction func rules(_ sender: Any)
    {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "rulesegue", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func start(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if team1Field.text != ""
        {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        let secondController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        secondController.team1String = team1Field.text!
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind I am a beginner so you might need to dumb it down for me.

I have a "home screen" and on that screen I have a text input for the user to enter their team name. then two buttons "start" and "rules"

Start goes to SecondViewController and I am trying to get "rules" to open rulesViewController by executing "rulesegue"

On this line of code I am getting the following error: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

```
 let secondController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
```

Not sure why.

Comment: `segue.destination` isn't actually a `SecondViewController`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to do it like this

```
if segue.identifier == "segue" {
    let secondController : SecondViewController = segue.destination as!  SecondViewController
    secondController.team1String = team1Field.text
}
```

or if you want to use segue.destination

```
if let secondController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController{
    secondController.team1String = team1Field.text
}
```

Comment: Your first example won't compile and one you fix that, it will crash just like the OP's code

Comment: Your second example simply prevents the crash but it doesn't fix the cause.

Comment: ah yes, it has an extra = sign. Sorry for that.

For the second one, I thought the cause is because he made sure that the destination is SecondViewController by the casting, but actually there could be other destination. So we need to make it as a conditional casting. using if let and an optionals.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, when the segue is performed to go to the Rules View Controller, your code is only sending segues to your second view controller.

You need to use this code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == ”rules” {
        let rulesController = segue.destination as! RulesViewController
    } else if segue.identifier == ”second” {
        let secondController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        secondController.team1String = team1Field.text!
    }
}
```

Then, you need to go into your storyboard and click on the little segue arrow/line to your RulesViewController and name the identifier to ”rules”, then do the same to the SecondViewController’s segue but name it ”second”

This code was all typed on my phone so if there are any errors let me know and I'll fix them. If you're confused write a comment and I can edit my answer.